# OAuth 2.0 service to service authentication and best practices

Tags: authentication, oauth, microservices

I have to deal with such type of auth flows:

1. Create auth flows for Web users;
2. In the same way deal with service to service authentication

Briefly following diagram can depict main components that we'll have:

[image]

For users Authentication we'd like to use OAuth2 (the Implicit Flow) and in general it looks more or less clear.

The question about service to service authorization can it be OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow used?

The main problem there that inside of datacenter1 it will be plenty of backend services that's why it will be good as services will work on the similar permission model as a users (at least some some functionality might be retracted ).

And additional question: what is the general recommendation for this use case if Authorization Server is inside of Datacenter1 or outside?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: OAuth 2.0 is not an authentication protocol, it is a delegated access protocol. It is clearly stated here: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Although widely adopted, the OAuth 2.0 "authentication framework" left many details open for interpretations - which commonly leads to security flaws of the implementation.
Check here for the 10 most common implementation vulnerabilities in OAuth 2.0: http://blog.intothesymmetry.com/2015/12/top-10-oauth-2-implementation.html

Therefore, the actual best practice is to use OpenID Connect, a similar protocol (built on top of OAuth 2.0), well defined, that mitigate most of the shortcomings of OAuth 2.0.

OpenID Connect is the best practice to authenticate end-users (mostly web).

If you want to authenticate within the datacenter, the variety of used solutions is somewhat wider - but overall I think the most common best practices are:

- "Leaner" implementation: clear HTTP when you appropriate network security (e.g. well-configured VPC, so access from the internet to any of these servers is very unlikely)
- "Safter" implementation: Server to Server Basic Authentication (or similar) over HTTPS, while rotating the key every now and then. The keys should be stored in a secure storage, such as [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)

In any case, it is best the service will *delegate the request for the user* (i.e. by providing `user_id` as part of the request) - and permissions will be enforced for this user:

- You probably don't want to allow a bug allowing one user to access the data of another user.
- In any case, it is much better logs / audit will be done with link to user originating the request, and not some generic "system user".